# How to print actual name of variable class type in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return variable name, but i keep getting this:

`<classes.man.man object at (some numbers (as example:0x03BDCA50))>`

Below is my code:

```py
from classes.man import man

def competition(guy1, guy2, counter1=0, counter2=0):
    .......................
    some *ok* manipulations
    .......................
    if counter1>counter2:
        return guy1

bob = man(172, 'green')
bib = man(190, 'brown')
print(competition(bob , bib ))
```

## Epilogue

If anyone want to, explain please what I can write instead of `__class__` in example below to get variable name.

```py
def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

Anyway, thank you for all of your support

Comment: The name of the variable in this case is `guy1`. I don't think that's actually what you want.

Comment: You should explain what output you actually want.

Comment: You definitly want to  read this https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - and then accept Valentin B. answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman he obviously wants the function to return either `"bob"` or `"bib"`... IOW it's the same old "how do y know the variable name" FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to approach your problem.

The simplest I can fathom is if you can change the class `man`, make it accept an optional name in its `__init__` and store it in the instance. This should look like this:

```
class man:
    def __init__(number, color, name="John Doe"):
        self.name = name
        # rest of your code here
```

That way in your function you could just do with:

```
    return guy1.name
```

Additionnally, if you want to go an extra step, you could define a `__str__` method in your class `man` so that when you pass it to `str()` or `print()`, it shows the name instead:

```
    # Inside class man
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

That way your function could just do:

```
    return guy1
```

And when you print the return value of your function it actually prints the name.

---

If you cannot alter class `man`, here is an extremely convoluted and costly suggestion, that could probably break depending on context:

```
import inspect
def competition(guy1, guy2, counter1=0, counter2=0):
    guy1_name = ""
    guy2_name = ""
    for name, value in inspect.stack()[-1].frame.f_locals.items():
        if value is guy1:
            guy1_name = name
        elif value is guy2:
            guy2_name = name
    if counter1 > counter2:
        return guy1_name
    elif counter2 > counter2:
        return guy1_name
    else:
        return "Noone"
```

Comment: There's a simpler and much safer solution for the second case: just return the winner object (`guy1` or `guy2`) and let the caller test which of it's own variables it matches, ie `winner = competition(bob, bill); if winner is bob: print("bob wins); elif winner is bill: # etc`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes indeed, there are several approaches as I said, your approach is much more reasonable but it is not dynamic (changing the variable name in the code to `john` will not print "john wins"). We don't really know what OP wants exactly so I laid out the simplest, most pythonic solution first and gave a nasty hack as a fallback in case it is needed.

Comment: "your approach is much more reasonable but it is not dynamic (changing the variable name in the code to john will not print "john wins")" => indeed, but at least with my solution using a dict of "man" instances or adding an intermediate function call  between the place where variables are defined and the call to `competition` will not break the `competition` function code - all changes are locals to the same place (the caller), which makes it much easier to maintain. My main point was that no hack was needed  here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I completely agree and your approach is a totally valid solution, less hacky than my second solution. It could very well be the accepted answer too in my book, if you disregard the obvious `name` attribute solution.

Answer (score 1):

Valentin's answer - the first part of it at least (adding a `name` attribute to `man`) - is of course the proper, obvious solution.

Now wrt/ the second part (the `inspect.stack` hack), it's brittle at best - the "variables names" we're interested in might not necessarily be defined in the first parent frame, and FWIW they could as well just come from a dict etc...

Also, it's definitly not the `competition()` function's responsability to care about this (don't mix domain layer with presentation layer, thanks), **and** it's totally useless since the caller code can easily solve this part by itself:

```
def competition(guy1, guy2, counter1=0, counter2=0):
    .......................
    some *ok* manipulations
    .......................
    if counter1>counter2:
        return guy1


def main():
    bob = man(172, 'green')
    bib = man(190, 'brown')

    winner = competition(bob, bib)
    if winner is bob:
        print("bob wins")
    elif winner is bib:
        print("bib wins")
    else:
        print("tie!")
```

Comment: I needed to output name of variable. Goal is to do that. Of course on practice I'd prefert he first part of Valentin's answer.

Comment: "name of variable" doesn't mean anything in Python, cf https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for in-depth explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Python prints the location of class objects in memory if they are passed to the `print()` function as default. If you want a prettier output for a class you need to define the `__repr__(self)` function for that class which should return a string that is printed if an object is passed to `print()`. Then you can just `return guy1`

Answer (score 0):

**`__repr__`** is the method that defines the name in your case.
By default it gives you the object type information. If you want to print more apt name then you should **override the __repr__** method

Check below code for instance

```
class class_with_overrided_repr:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "class_with_overrided_repr"

class class_without_overrided_repr:
    pass

x = class_with_overrided_repr()
print x    # class_with_overrided_repr

x = class_without_overrided_repr()
print x    #  <__main__.class_without_overrided_repr instance at 0x7f06002aa368>
```

Let me know if this what you want?

Comment: Almost. I want to get name of guy1 (bob in current example) if counter1>counter2

Comment: Okay, i see Valentin posted the correct solution above.